# Access $this Data on plugin magento

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

i built an after plugin and i need to access data inside $this.
[image]

In the image you can see the hierarchy.

The problem is that i need to access to the id of the CompanyModel value (22).

but inside $this i can only call $this->companyRepository and i can't access data from outside.
how can i access $this value (hopefully getting them as an object?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `id` is not a public property or doesnt even exist in the object, you can only access public property. Looks like `companyRepository` is the only public property in this class.

**Note:** Since your question and class structure is quite unclear, I am sorry I cant help you any further